# 'TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument' with Python 3 using super() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, super

I am writing an OOP program in Python 3 with inheritance and am running into the title error when I try to initialize the child class like so:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

    #more methods that to some stuff

class Child(Parent):
    a = 1 #a and b are class attributes
    b = 2

    def __init__(self, var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var3 = None):
        super().__init__(self, var1 = 1, var2 = 2) #error shows up for this line
        self.var3 = var3

child_obj = Child(var3 = 3)
```

When I create a `Child` object I get an error saying: `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'var1'`. Anyone know what could be wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get rid of the `=1`'s in the call to supers init - `__init__(self, var1, var2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your code it's wrong.
You want somthing like this?

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        print(var2)

    #more methods that to some stuff

class Child(Parent):
    a = 1 #a and b are class attributes
    b = 2

    def __init__(self, var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var3 = None):
        super().__init__(var1 = 1, var2 = 2) 
        self.var3 = var3

child_obj = Child(var3 = 3)
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I mentioned below the code that I tried to make a child object and then I got the error

Comment: So the above-mentioned code is satisfied with your requirements?

Comment: Check my post, I edited the code to better reflect what I want

Comment: Please check your code. In the class, you are passing parameters which is wrong. **class Parent(self, var1 = 1, var2 = 2):** and in super you are passing self which is not required. **super().__init__(self, var1 = 1, var2 = 2)** You sould not pass self. **super().__init__(self)**

Comment: That code is identical to mine... it still doesn't work. I made a mistake in typing the class definition here, that isn't how I had it in my code so that isn't the issue.

Comment: It is different. You are passing self to super class. which you are not suppose to.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Thanks